# Testing of 2 Smart Contracts using Truffle

Tags: truffle, testing

I'm writing 2 smart contracts: one is a satellite of the other. That is contract A is calling contract B. When I migrate in truffle all is OK, but when I try to run the tests it is not working. Is there any syntax or config file to modify to make it work?

The below is the migrations file used

```js
var One = artifacts.require("./LoanDataStorage");
var Two = artifacts.require("./LoanBusinessLogic");

module.exports = (deployer, network) => {
  deployer.deploy(One).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(Two, One.address)
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working" ? What is the error ?

Comment: We need the error, the contracts and the test to have a chance. The issue likely isn't in your migrations.

Comment: Hi Guys thank you for your interest but I solved it.. It was an issue in the paths of the contracts source code